# User-restricted resource access for aggregate endpoints

Tags: aggregation-framework, eve

Is there a way to apply [user-restricted resource access](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access) to aggregation endpoints?

I am currently using a mix of the resource access restriction and [pre-request event hooks](http://python-eve.org/features.html#pre-request-event-hooks) to restrict access to all endpoints, but it doesn't work for [aggregation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#mongodb-aggregation-framework) endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can now be achieved by adding an aggregation match filter via pre-request event hooks feature. The two new event hooks, `before_aggregation` and `after_aggregation`, are available in the development branch (`master`, version: `0.8-dev`) of python-eve .